# C Makefiles, multiple compilers

Tags: c, makefile, compilation

I am new to coding so please bear with me.  I have searched and have not been able to find a solution for my problem.  I working in C and I have multiple files that I have to compile using the c11 compiler and one file that I need to use GNU gcc with.  Is there a way to create a makefile that can do this with both compilers or is there a high level way that I am unaware of?
Thanks in advance

Comment: List all source files separately, and build their object files separately.

Comment: There's no such thing as "the" c11 compiler.

Answer (score 4):

The `CC` make variable tells make what C compiler to use. With GNU make it can be defined globally or on a per-target basis. The following should do what you want (assuming `foo.c` is the source file you want to compile with `gcc`):

```
CC := c11
foo.o: CC=gcc
```

Demonstration (with `clang` instead of `c11` because I do not have this one):

```
$ ls
bar.c  baz.c  foo.c  Makefile
$ cat Makefile
all: $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(wildcard *.c))
CC := clang
foo.o: CC=gcc
$ make
gcc    -c -o foo.o foo.c
clang    -c -o bar.o bar.c
clang    -c -o baz.o baz.c
```

Comment: Note that this is a GNU Make feature, not part of POSIX Make.